# Link to a document library in another subsite?

Tags: web-part, document-library

How can I display the same `Document Library`, **that already exists** in a `Subsite A`, in another `Subsite B` ?
I want to display a `Document Library` with all the columns (Title, Modified By ...) and not links to the original document library.
I already tried `Content Query Webpart` but it displays a list of `Links` to the original `Document Library`.

PS : I want to put the same documents in too different subsites without duplicating the files. I want to save the files in `Subsite A`, create a `Document Library` there and then create the same `Document Library` in `Subsite B` **without copying the files**.

Comment: You can save the list as template in SiteA and restore it in SiteB. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really. I edited my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily. You can try:

- Page Viewer Web Part, and just consume the library from Subsite A. When setting up the URL to the page, include IsDlg=1 at the end, that'll hide the ribbon and stuff: http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/
- Custom web part which pulls and reads the library, but you would have to recreate almost all the functionality around a library's UI (terrible idea)
- Use CQWP as you tried before, and live with the links ;) it's all in SharePoint anyway.

Using the first option, you could embed this on your page, ensure you have jQuery in there:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideItAll");

function hideItAll(){
    if(window.location.search.toLowerCase().indexOf("isdlg=1") > 0){
        $("#s4-ribbonrow").hide(); //ribbon bar

        //because the bar joins us late in the game, we need to throw CSS in to hide it
        $("head").append("<style>#Hero-WPQ2 { display:none }</style>");

        $("#CSRListViewControlDivWPQ2").hide(); //views and search bar
    }
}
</script>
```

Not sure how much you want to hide here, so i put it all in, remove what you'd like. Also you may have to check the second two IDs, that end in WPQ2, yours may be WPQ1 or 3? If you need help, you can use your dev toolbar to find your IDs, more help here: http://davidlozzi.com/2013/05/08/a-non-developers-intro-to-the-developer-toolbar-element-inspection/

Comment: I don't at this point, havent had much exposure to variations. Sorry

Comment: With the `IsDlg=1` it shows the "VARIATIONS / FILES / LIBRARY" Tab ... Do know how to hide this tab too ?

Comment: Some custom JS and CSS on the target page can help, not sure if that's possible?

Comment: Sure, I just thought I was missing a feature ... But apparently it is not possible without some custom code ... I say let's play ! :)

Comment: added code to post

Comment: Tried separately and works well thanks ! And what's the best way to apply the JS script only for this specific webpart ?

Comment: I throw it onto the view page in a script editor web part

Comment: The script works well when i tried separately in the console but not when using a script web part ! Do you know what could be the reason ?!

Comment: Any errors occur? Can you search the rendered page and see if the script tag is in there correctly? Sometimes you need to add the WP, save the script, then leave the page and come back for it to work properly.

Comment: Standby, found a bug, will update shortly.

Comment: updated code above. lmk

Comment: No errors but the Script Web Part is still not acting on the Page View one ...

Comment: have you tried outside of the page viewer, just change the URL of the page to include isdlg? I'm trying a page viewer now

Comment: Yes in a separete page it works fine even with the first code .I mean when i open the Document Library URL in a new Tab and run the script in the console everything works fine but not with Web Parts ...

Comment: Ah, ok, the updated code above works for me when inserted in a script web part, i added a delay to the script to wait for the page components to load. Also, i tested in a page viewer webpart and it works as expected ;)

Comment: Still not working for me ! Even when i launch the script on the page that contains the Page View Web Part (with the Document Librayr URL?isdlg=1) ... It doesn't hide anything ! It only work when I open the URL+isdlg=1 on a new tab and launch the script ...

Comment: To be clear : I use, in the same Page, a Page View Web Part using the Document Library UR?Lisdlg=1. And a Script Editor Web Part on which I put the js script ...

Comment: ahh.... you need to put the script on the library page, so the page that is the URL you're embeding and using the isdlg on

Comment: I put a Script Editor Webpart in the same page where I have my Page View Webpart but doesn't work

Comment: The script above has to go into the page that is in the page viewer, not the page that has the page viewer, so whatever the URL is you're using, that page should have the script

Comment: Can you please be more explicit and explain to me what should be where ? I'm actually using a page on which i put Page View WP and Script Editor WP. In the PVWP i put the URL with the Islg parameter and in the SEWP I put the script (Both of them in the same page and the URL used in the PVWP is the one of the document library which is in another subsite ... ). This doesn't work

Comment: Parent page - put the PVWP with the URL having isdlg. Daughter Page - put the SEWP with the code.

Comment: So the two web parts (Page View and Script Editor) shouldn't be in the same page (That's actually what I am doing) ?! What do you mean by Parent / Daughter pages please ?

Comment: The parent page has the PVWP on it, and is consuming the daughter page inside the PVWP. The daughter page should have the script on it. The two web parts should not be on the same page, so if the PVWP is on one page, the script web part should be on the other.

Comment: I use the parent and daughter as terms to mean the parent web page is the one with the PVWP, which points to the url?isdlg=1. The daughter page is the page AT the url you're pointing to, and that page is the page to put the SEWP on.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in SharePoint 2016.

This is for displaying a webpart, `target` in some other site in the collection.

1. In SharePoint Designer, open `target`'s view's page (`AllItems.aspx`, for example)
2. Find `<ExportControlledProperties>False</ExportControlledProperties>`, change it to True. Save the page.
3. In your browser, navigate to `target`'s page. Click Site Actions -> Edit Page.
4. Click the arrow on the top right of the webpart -> Export.
5. Save the file somewhere.

Now, in SP2016, importing this webpart as-is gave me an error. To fix it:

6. Find the GUID of the site that owns `target`.

   1. In `target`'s site, go to the Site Settings
   2. Enable Tree View (temporarily, you can disable once we're done)
   3. Go to the site's main page. View the page's source.
   4. Find `ListNode:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX:XXX...`
   5. Copy the first GUID (before the first colon). That's the site's GUID.
7. Open `target.webpart` that you saved in step 5 in a text editor.
8. Find `<property name="WebId" ... >00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>`
9. Replace the zeroes with the site's GUID from step 6. Save the file.
10. Upload `target.webpart` in the Insert Webpart menu.

Sources:

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-one-library-multiple-sites.html
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/02/sharepoint-finding-site-guid-sharepoint.html