# Sharepoint 2013 - Hide ribbon in page viewer web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have an overarching document library that I have created several views. I intend on using the views through the page viewer web part. While I am referencing the default view the below mentioned post and its solution works until I change to a different view. Can anyone assist?

[Link to a document library in another subsite?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118597/link-to-a-document-library-in-another-subsite/118598#118598)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue myself.
After thinking about the process of placing the JS into the parent page - I realised with each new view I created it displayed it in a new page - simple - insert JS in each new view page.